# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] al instalar magento

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de instalar Magento por cmd en Windows pero me sale un error al instalarlo por comando con una configuracion del archivo  InstallCommand.php en XAMPP en la linea 282 y no tengo claro que se sumone que tengo que cambiar. Esta es la linea actual:
throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Parameter validation failed');

Tambien muestra este error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.